# Postfix : error: unsupported dictionary type: mysql

Tags: postfix, ubuntu-14.04

I've a problem w/ postfix

problem:

```
# tail -f /var/log/mail.err
Aug 20 17:57:50 myserver postfix/smtpd[8243]: error: unsupported dictionary type: mysql
Aug 20 17:57:50 myserver postfix/smtpd[8243]: error: unsupported dictionary type: mysql
Aug 20 17:58:05 myserver postfix/smtpd[8244]: error: unsupported dictionary type: mysql
Aug 20 17:58:05 myserver postfix/smtpd[8244]: error: unsupported dictionary type: mysql
Aug 20 18:00:38 myserver postfix/smtpd[8277]: error: unsupported dictionary type: mysql
Aug 20 18:00:38 myserver postfix/smtpd[8277]: error: unsupported dictionary type: mysql
Aug 20 18:03:32 myserver postfix/smtpd[8320]: error: unsupported dictionary type: mysql
Aug 20 18:03:32 myserver postfix/smtpd[8320]: error: unsupported dictionary type: mysql
Aug 20 18:03:33 myserver postfix/trivial-rewrite[8322]: error: unsupported dictionary type: mysql
Aug 20 18:03:33 myserver postfix/trivial-rewrite[8322]: error: unsupported dictionary type: mysql
```

idea?

Comment: almost-duplicate question for pcre: https://serverfault.com/q/972173/250204

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**[SOLVED]** This fixed the issue for me in Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo apt-get install postfix-mysql
```

Comment: `sudo pacman -S postfix-mysql` - For the record, this same package was also the solution on Arch

Answer (score 14):

1. Check output of `postconf -m`. It will look like this:

   ```
   root@ds94:/usr/local/etc/postfix # postconf -m
   btree
   cidr
   environ
   fail
   hash
   internal
   memcache
   mysql
   pcre
   proxy
   regexp
   socketmap
   static
   tcp
   texthash
   unix
   ```
2. If in output of postconf there isn't `mysql` string, it means that postfix is built without mysql support. To resolve it install `postfix-mysql` package.

Answer (score 2):

Check if installed: `dpkg -s postfix-mysql`

if not install `sudo apt-get -y install postfix-mysql`

Problem solved.

Comment: funny fact, I have it installed and still that error

Comment: Try adding `mysql   /usr/lib/postfix/postfix-mysql.so.1.0.1 dict_mysql_open` to `/etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf` and do a postfix reload

Comment: @GuidoGoluke Thanks a million! That's exactly what I needed to fix my borked machine!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error when `/etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf` had write permissions for group. Apparently, postfix then ignores the contents.