# "unsupported dictionary type: pcre" postfix header_checks

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

I have the following header_checks in place on Postfix

```
/^Received:/ IGNORE
/^X-Originating-IP:/    IGNORE
/^X-Mailer:/            IGNORE
/Message-Id:\s+<(.*?)@www.mainserver.com>/   REPLACE Message-Id: <$1@www.domain.com>
/X-Mailer-LID:/        IGNORE
/^MIME-Version:/i PREPEND Precedence: bulk
/X-Mailer-RecptId:/        IGNORE
/X-Mailer-SID:/        IGNORE
/X-Mailer-Sent-By:/        IGNORE
/List-Unsubscribe:/        IGNORE
```

Once I activate them in `postfix/main.cf` (after running `postmap /etc/postfix/header_checks`) postfix stops working. When I attempt to send an email I get the following error log

```
Jun 20 03:19:26 mail postfix/pickup[6813]: F37593F946: uid=0 from=<root@domain.com>
Jun 20 03:19:26 mail postfix/cleanup[6819]: warning: pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks is unavailable. unsupported dictionary type: pcre
Jun 20 03:19:26 mail postfix/cleanup[6819]: warning: pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks lookup error for "Received: by mail.domain.com (Postfix, from userid 0)??id F37593F946; Thu, 20 Jun 2019 03:19:26 +0200"
Jun 20 03:19:26 mail postfix/cleanup[6819]: warning: F37593F946: header_checks map lookup problem -- message not accepted, try again later
Jun 20 03:19:26 mail postfix/pickup[6813]: warning: maildrop/F27653F945: error writing F37593F946: queue file write error
Jun 20 03:19:27 mail postfix/pickup[6813]: F42373F946: uid=0 from=<root@domain.com>
Jun 20 03:19:27 mail postfix/cleanup[6819]: warning: pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks is unavailable. unsupported dictionary type: pcre
Jun 20 03:19:27 mail postfix/cleanup[6819]: warning: pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks lookup error for "Received: by mail.domain.com (Postfix, from userid 0)??id F42373F946; Thu, 20 Jun 2019 03:12:51 +0200"
Jun 20 03:19:27 mail postfix/cleanup[6819]: warning: F42373F946: header_checks map lookup problem -- message not accepted, try again later
Jun 20 03:19:27 mail postfix/pickup[6813]: warning: maildrop/2C3F23F172: error writing F42373F946: queue file write error
Jun 20 03:19:27 mail postfix/pickup[6813]: 00EE13F946: uid=0 from=<root@domain.com>
Jun 20 03:19:27 mail postfix/cleanup[6819]: warning: pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks is unavailable. unsupported dictionary type: pcre
Jun 20 03:19:27 mail postfix/cleanup[6819]: warning: pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks lookup error for "Received: by mail.domain.com (Postfix, from userid 0)??id 00EE13F946; Thu, 20 Jun 2019 03:13:36 +0200"
Jun 20 03:19:27 mail postfix/cleanup[6819]: warning: 00EE13F946: header_checks map lookup problem -- message not accepted, try again later
Jun 20 03:19:27 mail postfix/pickup[6813]: warning: maildrop/924363F173: error writing 00EE13F946: queue file write error
```

What is causing this? I believe it works on my old CentOS 6 installation but I am having problems with my Ubuntu 18.04 installation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*pcre* support is distributed in a separate package in Ubuntu. You can have [postfix](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/postfix) installed without having [postfix-pcre](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/postfix-pcre) installed.

You can confirm that this is your problem by listing all available lookup table types, typically you will have *regexp* installed but *pcre* missing:

```
$ postconf -m | grep re
betree
regexp
```

You can install the *pcre* lookup table type using:

```
sudo apt install postfix-pcre
```

Restart *postfix* and review your logs for potential errors with your (now for the first time loaded) maps:

```
sudo systemctl restart postfix
sudo journalctl -u postfix@-.service
```

Note that using `postmap` to update *pcre*-type files has no useful effect. The utility will (when not specified otherwise) assume the default database type `hash:` and produce a `.db`  output for that. Which is not used for *pcre*.

Comment: Ah! This definitely explains a _lot_. I guess that `regexp` are 'old-style' regular expressions, while `pcre`, well, as the name implies, are [Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](https://pcre.org/)...

Comment: This last paragraph was the key for me; I was getting "postmap: fatal: unsupported dictionary type: pcre does not support bulk-mode creation." when trying to run `postmap pcre:/etc/postfix/virtual`.

Comment: @miken32 'postmap /etc/postfix/virtua' without 'pcre:'