# "smtp_header_checks" in postfix not including the header

Tags: postfix, amazon-ses, smtp-headers

I am trying to add AWS SES's `X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET` header in my postfix. For this I am using `smtp_header_checks` as follows:

My `main.cf` has the following line:

`smtp_header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks`

header_checks file is as follows:

`/^From:/ PREPEND X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET: <name_of_my_config_set>`

When I send mail, I dont see any header with name `X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET`

What do I need to fix to get this header? My postfix version is 3.4

Edit: I looked both in main.cf and master.cf for `receive_override_options` and I dont see it in either files

Comment: Are you actually submitting the mail to an affected `smtp` service (not overriding cleanup service to one with alternate header checks)? Did you try the `WARN` command in place of `PREPEND` to trigger a log? Did you review postfix startup logs noting a failure to parse or [utilize](https://serverfault.com/a/972314/250204) your header_checks file? style note: use `postconf -M` and `postconf -n` to dump settings.